# Convert list of java object in javascript arraylist

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, autocomplete, struts

I have a question: I have a java object that's a `List<User>` and I want pass it to javascript for populate the source of a jQuery autocomplete.
From jsp I pass the object present in the session by this tag

```
<input type="hidden" id="all_users" value=" < s: property value="#session.allUsers" /> " />
```

Then in javascript

```
var allUsers = $('#all_users').val().replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',');
```

Now I don't know what's next step because I obtain value as bean.User@4a255c. How I can convert this object for manage it in javascript and obtain the values that contains?

Comment: You could use JSON. For instance, use Jackson to serialize your `List<User>` to a JSON array, then parse it using JavaScript's builtin JSON capabilities to make it an array.

Comment: Have you tried using JSON.parse on the allUsers value?

Comment: How big is the list? Is it required that you have the data in the client page, or is Ajax enough? Is the JS external to the JSP?

Comment: The list could be big and has 3 field for every item. Now I tried JSON and the conversion of java object in json object is ok, but when I pass the value in the jsp through this tag:

<input type="hidden" id="all_users" value="<s:property value="#session.allUsers"/>"/>

in javascript the parsing of that value not work because it's a unknow object... Here I show how I wrote:

var allUsers = $('#all_users');
var array = JSON.parse(allUsers);

where is the problem?

Comment: Problem risolved, I forget of call method .val()

var allUsers = $('#all_users').val();
var array = JSON.parse(allUsers);

Now is Ok, JSON is very powerful!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have experience with struts but you may try something like the following:

```
<input type="hidden" id="all_users" value=" < s: property value="#Arrays.toString(session.allUsers.toArray())" /> " />
```

Comment: And yes I agree with the comments, that JSON would be a better alternative.

Comment: Can someone give me some example or guide of how I do it with JSON? Thanks